Run PhpStorm macro via external tool
Is it possible to somehow run a recorded macro in PhpStorm through external tools? So that by customizing the main toolbar, I can place a button to call an external tool there and run this macro on click.
I want to be able to run a macro not only with a keyboard shortcut, but also by clicking on an interface element in IDE.  In short, I want to do the same thing with a click as with a keyboard shortcut.
